# How to take response from controller?

Tags: java, angular, rest, typescript

In my angular 4 application, I am able to call my rest service but i am not able to print my response. What am I missing? Below is my code.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/rest/auth")
    public Response authenticateUser() 
    {
        String token = issue("test");
         AnimalTok tok = new AnimalTok();
         tok.setTo(token);
         return Response.ok(tok).build();
    }
```

ts file call:

```
 getAnimalData():  Promise<string> {
    let context:String =  document.location.pathname.substring(0, document.location.pathname.indexOf("/",2)) + "/";
    return this.http.get(context  + 'rest/auth/')
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.text() as string)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Getting the below exception:

```
errors.ts:42 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 404 OK for URL: http://localhost:89795/rest/auth/
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:809)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:775)
    at zone.js:858
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.ts:288)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:500)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1517)
```

Comment: Your TS looks fine. Have you tried logging the response? console.log(response)

Comment: @sTg Are you using HttpClient?

Comment: yeah i am using it

Comment: the error shows that your url isn't correct (404 URL NOT FOUND). May be remove end '/' from url.